# Firing an input changed event when decimals are entered into a number input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

The HTML:

```
<input id="example" type="number"/>
```

The JS:

```
$("#example").on("input", function (e) { 
    debugger;
});
```

The issue is as follows. If the content of the field is `1000`, and the user enters a decimal (`.`), to make it `1000.`, it does not fire the `input` event in Chrome. Is this normal, and if so, then how can I make it fire an event to be able to detect it?

Comment: Did you try with "change" event instead?

Comment: @NikitaKurtin Yeah, but it's not good for what I need, because the change event doesn't fire immediately after text is entered.

Comment: Seems to work just fine on Chrome `47.0.2526.106 m` for me. See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ykuhguwo/) (using Jquery 2.1.4). The value will be blank because the number isn't valid when you have `1000.`, but it definitely still fires the event.

Comment: Which version of Chrome? This could be a bug because `1000` and `1000.` are parsed to the same number, so the browser might think the value did not change.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I'm on version `Version 47.0.2526.106 m`, but then what version of jQuery are you guys on?

Comment: I don't think the version of jQuery is relevant here, `input` is a native DOM event. For what it's worth, does the behavior remain the same if you remove the `type="number"` attribute?

Comment: I just check it, it seem to be about the type as @FrédéricHamidi just mention. Since it's explicitly define to number and "1000." isn't a valid number. Check for the same Chrome version (mentioned above). 
so "1000" works successfully and also "1000.0"

Comment: @Nikita, actually `1000.` is a valid number in JavaScript. It is equivalent to `1000.0`, or plain `1000`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yes but, my point was that's it isn't passed in - because of the "." after the number. I checked for: 10, 100, 1000, 1000. and 1000.0 
All worked except of "1000." 
After that I checked any other number with "." in the end - and it's also didn't passed in.

Comment: @NikitaKurtin So it isn't just me. I knew it.

Comment: Yeah, anyway as said earlier - removing the `type="number"` should help.

Comment: @NikitaKurtin Yeah, I know but, then I lose the arrow up/down in HTML5 in Chrome/Firefox/possibly Edge but I haven't tested that one.

Comment: @Alexandru You can then store the last (current) number, and use it if a new value wasn't passed.

Comment: @NikitaKurtin Ideally what I would like to do is get an event for when text content is about to be rendered, and modify that text content before it is rendered using something like `this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "")`, but I must be living in a dream world since I don't think that this shittily designed HTML tag of `type="number"` can handle that and probably requires some intensive hacks to pull off as a different type of input. Oh well.

Comment: It fires for me, so it's either your Chrome version, or your jquery that is the problem. Event if the input event is a native one, you're attaching a jquery handler, so, in fact, the jquery version might be the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in previous comment, the problem is that a number with dot "." in the end doesn't passed in. So here is something you can do:

```js
$(function(){
  var lastNum;
  $("#example").on("input", function (e) {
    if(this.value.length>0)lastNum=this.value;//if value passed in correctly - update it
    console.debug(lastNum);//Do anything with the lastNum
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="example" type="number"/>
```